# If I define a move constructor and don't need a copy constructor, why would I need to define a copy constructor?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, move-constructor, function-object

Using Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29) -std=c++17,
the following code does not compile

```
struct C {
  C()  {}
  C(C&& other) {std::cout << "move\n";}
  //C(const C& other) {std::cout << "copy\n";}
  void operator()(float x) {}
};

int main(){
  std::function<void(float)> f = C();
}
```

unless I uncomment the copy constructor.  Yet when I run the executable, I find out that the copy constructor is never called.

Does the standard require that a copy constructor be defined in this scenario?  If so, why?  If not, why does the code not compile?

I have resisted adding a copy constructor because, in the code from which this minimal example was derived, the class has a member of type `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: *Yet when I run the executable, I find out that the copy constructor is never called.* -- You can't determine whether the code is valid this way.  The code must follow the rules of C++, even though the compiler may optimize away the copy.

Comment: @cpplearner Thank you!  That is what I needed to know.  Do you want to form an answer that I can upvote?  Or is my question too similar to the one you cited?